# AdMob libgdx. Ads aren't displayed

Tags: libgdx, admob, ads

The problem is that on resolution 540x960 (my phone) the ads work good, but on other resolutions they aren't. It's an error: "Not enough space to show ad". I think it's probably something wrong with layout, but I don't know what.

My MainActivity:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();           
        //initialize(new JumpJackieJump(this), cfg);          

        this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);          
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //no title is needed         

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId(ADCODE);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

        ad = new InterstitialAd(this);
        ad.setAdUnitId(FULLADCODE);

        View gameView = initializeForView(new JumpJackieJump(new RequestHandler(adView, ad), this), cfg);           

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        AdRequest fadReq = new AdRequest.Builder().build();          

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);           
        ad.loadAd(fadReq);          

        layout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        layout.addView(gameView);           

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);         
        layout.addView(adView, adParams);               

        setContentView(layout);     

        if (!ad.isLoaded())
            ad.loadAd(fadReq);          

        ad.setAdListener(new AdListener() 
        {
          @Override
          public void onAdClosed() 
          {
            AdRequest fadReq = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            ad.loadAd(fadReq);
          }
        });
```

Comment: Did the solution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically load adsize based on the devices' screen resolutions:

```
     AdSize adSize = AdSize.SMART_BANNER;  

        DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();  
        double density = dm.density * 160;
        double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / density, 2);
        double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / density, 2);
        double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);   
        if (screenInches > 8) { // > 728 X 90
            adSize = AdSize.LEADERBOARD;
        } else if (screenInches > 6) { // > 468 X 60
            adSize = AdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE;
        } else { // > 320 X 50
            adSize = AdSize.BANNER;
        }

        adView = new AdView(this);
         adView.setAdUnitId(FULLADCODE); 
         adView.setAdSize(adSize);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
         adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try your code, but what with interstitial ads?

Comment: As far as I know, you have no control over the size of interstitial ads. You can only set the ad types to be shown within the admob console